# не могу поменять значение после первого использования

Tags: powershell, rust, cargo

здраствуйте, решил сделать поиск определенного текста в файле, такой своеобразный grep,
есть 2 режима: чувствительный поиск:

```
 pub fn search<'a>(_content: &'a str, _query: &str ) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    _content.lines().filter(|line| line.contains(_query)).collect()
}
```

а так же нечувствительный:

```
pub fn search_without_lowcase<'a>(_contaitner: &'a str, _query: &str) -> Vec<&'a str>{
    _contaitner.lines().filter(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&_query.to_lowercase())).collect()

}
```

выбор какой использовать осуществляется через:

```
 let mut _lowacase =  env::var("LOW").is_err();
```

так вот какая у меня проблема:
я не могу осуществить (если это возможно, многоразовый выбор,
если один раз я выбрал `&env:LOW=0` то он уже не станет равен 1, а что бы воспользоваться нечувствительным поиском, придется перезапускать powershell..
вот весь код:

```
use std::{ env, fs, io};

pub struct Fileseach{
pub _filename: String,
pub _query: String,
pub _lowacase: bool
```

}

```
impl Fileseach {
pub fn new(mut args: env::Args) -> Result<Fileseach, &'static str>{
    args.next();
    
    let _filename = match args.next(){
        Some(arg) => arg,
        None => return Err("не удалось считать название файла"),
    };
    let _query = match args.next() {
        Some(arg) => arg,
        None => return Err("не удалось считать поисковый запрос"),
        
    };
    let mut _lowacase =  env::var("LOW").is_err();
    Ok(Fileseach{_filename, _query, _lowacase})

}
pub fn search<'a>(_content: &'a str, _query: &str ) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    _content.lines().filter(|line| line.contains(_query)).collect()
}
pub fn search_without_lowcase<'a>(_contaitner: &'a str, _query: &str) -> Vec<&'a str>{
    _contaitner.lines().filter(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&_query.to_lowercase())).collect()

}
pub fn run(_filesearch: Fileseach)-> Result<(), io::Error>{
 let _content = fs::read_to_string(_filesearch._filename).expect("не удалось счиатть файл");
if _filesearch._lowacase {
    for line in  Fileseach::search_without_lowcase(&_content, &_filesearch._query){
        println!("{}", line);
       };
}
else{
    for line in  Fileseach::search(&_content, &_filesearch._query){
    println!("{}", line);
   };}
   Ok(())
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что ты не понимаешь, что делает строка

```rust
let mut _lowacase =  env::var("LOW").is_err();
```

Функция [`std::env::var`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var.html) имеет следующую сигнатуру

```rust
pub fn var<K: AsRef<OsStr>>(key: K) -> Result<String, VarError>
```

Т.е. она принимает любой тип, из которого можно получить ссылку на `OsStr` и возвращает `Result<String, VarError>`, который обозначает успех или ошибку в зависимости от того, есть такая переменная окружения или нет. Если переменная существует, то `Result` будет иметь значение `Ok(String)` и эта строка и будет значением переменной `"LOW"` (видимо в твоём случае `"0"` или `"1"`).

Твоя строчка кода в итоге означает, что `_lowacase` всегда `false`, если переменная окружения `"LOW"` существует и при этом не важно, какое значение у этой переменной.

Если ты хочешь менять переменную `_lowacase` в зависимости от значения `"LOW"`, то тебе нужно смотреть значение полученной строки. Например так

```rust
let _lowacase = env::var("LOW").map(|v| v != "0").unwrap_or_default();
```

Это означает, что если переменная `"LOW"` существует и она не равна `"0"`, то `_lowacase` будет `true`, иначе `false`.